# Qt5 Widget Properties from UI

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

I'm in the process of transitioning from PyQt5 to Qt5 in C++ and I'm having a bit of a tough time. I created a simple UI that contains a Qwidget called `logo`. I'm trying to make this widget an SVG rendering widget with this code:

```
QSvgRenderer renderer(QString(":/LogoSVG.svg"));

QImage image(500, 200, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
image.fill(0x000000);

QPainter painter(&image);
renderer.render(&painter);
```

In Python, I'd create a simple widget class that renders the SVG then in the UI form loader class I'd do

```
self.logo = SVGRender(self)
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in C++ Qt, so here's what I have so far and it's returning the error `error: cannot convert ‘logoW’ to ‘QWidget*’ in assignment`

example.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#include "ui_example.h"

class example : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    example(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    Ui::example ui;

};

class logoW: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    logoW(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif
```

example.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSvgRenderer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <iostream>
#include "example.h"

using namespace std;


example::example(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

    ui.setupUi(this);

    ui.logo = logoW(this)

}


logoW :: logoW(QWidget * parent = 0){

    QSvgRenderer renderer(QString(":resources/LogoSvg.svg"));

    QImage image(500, 200, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    image.fill(0xaaA08080); 

    QPainter painter(&image);

    renderer.render(&painter);

}
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable ui.logo requires a pointer of the object, in your case it changes:

```
ui.logo = logoW(this);
```

to:

```
ui.logo = new logoW(this);
```

I also understand that you want to display the image in the logo widget. To do this you must implement the `paintEvent` method:

***.h**

```
class logoW: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    logoW(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
```

***.cpp**

```
logoW::logoW(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
}

void logoW::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    Q_UNUSED(event)
    QSvgRenderer renderer(QString(":resources/LogoSvg.svg"));

    QPainter painter(this);

    renderer.render(&painter);
}
```

Comment: Welp, adding `new` allowed it to compile and your edit made it work. Thank you for your help and now I know what I did wrong.